# Why aren't the decimals printed to the string?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In order to get a string with 2 decimals value I've tried:

```
   [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[self CurrentValue] doubleValue]]]
```

this

```
   [self CurrentValue] stringValue]
```

and this:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:[self CurrentValue]];
    [formatter release];
```

But it doesn't work. THe original number is a float = 22, and I always get a string "22", and not "22.00".

Thanks

Comment: Weird - the first code sample you give should work!  Have you tried logging it straight after?

Comment: Don't know whether this helps, but try this: `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[self CurrentValue] floatValue]]]` or `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lf",[[self CurrentValue] doubleValue]]]`.

Comment: The first one indeed is correct and should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a few test scenarios and hopefully this can help you get to the bottom of it.  The formatter is ideal if you are doing a currency, otherwise string1 is ideal.  To work from this example you can set number up - `NSNumber * number = [self CurrentValue];`

```
NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:22];
NSString * string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[number doubleValue]];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
NSString *string2 = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
[formatter release];

NSLog(@"string 1 %@\nstring 2 %@\nstring 3 %@", string1, string2, [number stringValue]);

//output
string 1 22.00
string 2 $22.00
string 3 22

// top code with NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:22];
string 1 22.00
string 2 $22.00
string 3 22

// top code with NSNumber * number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:22.0];
string 1 22.00
string 2 $22.00
string 3 22
```

Summary:
The way the number is created is not significant here to the output if it is truly an int (floats with such as 4.20 will work as expected in every case, but every int value 22,22.0,22.000 gets treated the same by all 3 ways of creating a number.  So choose the format you like best and implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have extra `[]` around. You can try

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[self CurrentValue] floatValue]]`

or

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lf",[[self CurrentValue] doubleValue]]` both are good to go.

Comment: Usually, when the questioner's syntax is invalid but the problem they're asking about is bad behavior/output at run time, it means the code in the question is fictional, typed uncompiled into the question form, so whatever syntax errors it has are not the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have tried the code and the only issues in that I got was of the parenthesis so I thought I'd rather suggest him that he has some issues with that else other is working great.

Answer (score 0):

It actually much simpler.
You said that "The original number is a float = 22". Now, remember that obj-c runtime class may differ from declared one. And when you instantiate your float variable with actually integer value - it is an integer one at runtime! You should change it to one of the following:
float someFloatValue = 22f;
float someFloatValue = 22.0;
float someFloatValue = (float)22; (not sure about that one thought)

Happy coding...